# Date Pipe value in Angular - 'Unable to convert "20:28:08.146604+00:00" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, fastapi

I want to make a `Date pipe` to an attribut of an object (Note object) in Angular. here's the Model:

```
export class Notes{
    constructor(public post_name: string, public content: string
        , public post_id: number, public user_id: number,
        public user_name: string, public email: string,
         public id_user: number,
        public created_at : Date 
         ){}
}
```

here is the code that fetch the data from the API (I store the result in list of type `Notes`):

```
ShowNotes(){            
        return  this.http.get<Notes[] | [] >(this.server+'/posts')
}
```

the schema in my API of the data :

```
class All_details(BaseModel):
       post_name: str
       content: str
       post_id: int
       user_id: int
       user_name:str
       email: str
       id_user: int
       created_at :time
```

the `created_at` attribut is generated automaticaly in Postgres and it's of type `time with time zone`
when I do tests with `Postman`the created_at has this form `"created_at": "17:45:57.639281+00:00"`

here is how I try to make the Pipe

```
<p class="tim"> {{post.created_at | date }} </p>
```

I understand that the API send a string format but normally when I have defiend created_at as Date type, typescript must convert the string format into Date

I'm not sure what causing the problem (Angular or the API) so I used them both in the tags.

Comment: I cannot format that as a `Date` because the date part of the created_at timestamp is missing -- it's just the time. The way your Postgres is set up just discards important information, so start by changing that to store the date part as well.

Comment: @Clashsoft What kind of configuration can I do in Postgres more that setting the type to `Time with time zone`and default as  `now()` ?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html, you probably need `timestamp with time zone`, or maybe without time zone

Comment: @Clashsoft Exactly. this is what I've done.
and then in my API I set the type as `datetime.datetime`
in Angular `new Date(dateToConvert)`

Comment: time with type zone gave me this format : `"17:45:57.639281+00:00"`which is not working for me. and timestamp with time zone gave me this format : `"2023-01-21T12:00:02.341646+00:00"`
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot format that as a Date because the date part of the `created_at` timestamp is missing -- it's just the time.
The way your Postgres is set up just discards important information, so start by changing that to store the date part as well.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html, you probably need `timestamp with time zone`, or maybe just `timestamp` (without time zone).